# node webkit installer for a single user

Tags: node.js, exe, node-webkit

I have created a software using nodejs and express, I packaged it and created an executable using node-webkit. I will deliver the file to my client. But the problem is that if my client copy the files and put it on another computer, he can still use the app. How do I create an exe file using node-webkit for only one pc?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you only want one computer to be able to run that executable, ever?

Comment: yes........... need help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the physical address of the computer

```
var expectedMacAddress = '',
    currentSystemMacAddress = '';

if ( expectedMacAddress == currentSystemMacAddress ){
    // continue running app
} else {
    // exit app. Display limited license warning
}
```